# DeviceIoControl is totally not working, SystemBuffer empty on return

Tags: c++, io, driver, ioctl

i have got an IOCTL being sendt down to my driver with a structure, the structure is passed successfully, then my driver does its magic, but when its done it should return a simple unsigned _int64 which is 8 bytes long, i set the IRP's IoStatus.Information to the size of unsigned _int64(8 bytes) and i copy the value to the AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer and lastly i set the IoStatus.Status to STATUS_SUCCESS then call IoCompleteRequest.

Now, i checked with WinDbg that the SystemBuffer contains the correct output and that the Status and Information fields are correct upon the call to IoCompleteRequest, yet when my usermode application's call to DeviceIoControl returns the output buffer does not change the value of the integer that i am pointing to in the lpOutBuffer field. i initialize it to just a plain 0x9 on creation and it remains the same value when the call is finished, when it should be something entirely different, i have multiple IOCTL's which all work and are made in the exsact same way, i am clueless what is happening here, any tips would be greatly appreciated and i am led to believe that this is a windows bug now or something like that, as i have read through my code 100 times without figuring this simple yet complex bug out.

Im sorry that i cannot post any code as i do not own it and for other reasons.

Comment: _Im sorry that i cannot post any code as i do not own it and for other reasons._ And.. We are not asking you to post the actual code. You need to **manufacture** [mcve], so that 1) we can reproduce the problem, and 2) you don't post actual code.

Comment: well there is not much to it, send a struct with some data down to a device, send back a 64 bit integer and then its gone on return and i have no way to check what the buffer is in usermode as the only thing we have access to is the DeviceIoControl call itself.

Comment: ok, how about `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` in user mode on return ? are it as filled in your driver code ? may be this *ioctl* used not `METHOD_BUFFERED` ?

Comment: @RbMm correct me if im wrong, but the usermode code does not have access to the IO_STATUS_BLOCK itself right ? i thought the IO manager only copied data from it to the output buffer specified in DeviceIoControl ? and yeah the IOCTL is METHOD_BUFFERED just like my other IOCTLs.

Comment: you totally wrong. user mode of course **always**  must use `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` (as and kernel mode). if you use `ZwDeviceIoControlFile` you explicitly `IO_STATUS_BLOCK`, if you use `DeviceIoControl` - `OVERLAPPED` (Internal, InternalHigh) is `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` (pointer to `OVERLAPPED` passed as pointer to `IO_STATUS_BLOCK`) if you not explicitly pass  `OVERLAPPED` - system do this implicitly. but in all case `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` is used and data is copied from kernel to user mode `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` - so look - how it filled on output. in your case this is  `OVERLAPPED` (first 2 members)

Comment: @RbMm yeah i tried it out now and indeed you are right, allthought the problem still remains and the IO_STATUS_BLOCK.Status is STATUS_SUCCESS(0x0) and Information is 8 which is the size of a 64 bit integer :/ still the output buffer does not receive the integer and remains unchanged. Any ideas ?

Comment: @Paze - so if `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` filled correct (Information is 8 , Status is 0  (can for absolute sure fill  `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` with another values *before* IOCTL )) - this mean that in general IOCTL is executed in driver ok, but.. without any code snippet very hard to say why your buffer not filled as excepted

Answer (score 3):

Hope you found the solution since you posted this question 3 years ago. We ran across this post while investigating something similar, the solution is very simple but not documented.
If the driver copies some data to the output buffer and uses WdfRequestComplete with status OK, nothing is returned to the caller! You need to call WdfRequestCompleteWithInformation and pass the number of bytes written in the Information parameter. This will tell the framework how many bytes to return to the caller.

E.g.:

```
WDFMEMORY   reqMemory;
NTSTATUS    status = WdfRequestRetrieveOutputMemory(Request, &reqMemory);
if (!NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
    break;
}
WdfMemoryCopyFromBuffer(reqMemory, 0, data, dataLen);

/* this will complete the request but nothing is returned to the caller
WdfRequestComplete(Request, S_OK);
*/
/* this is the correct way of returning the data */
WdfRequestCompleteWithInformation(Request, S_OK, dataLen);
```

Comment: I remember reading conflicting/confusing things about `WdfRequestCompleted` vs. `WdfRequestCompletedWithInformation`. The docs suggest that the latter allows you to return some kind of extra out-of-band information. Anyway, I was struggling to figure out why my custom IOCTL driver commands weren't returning any data. **THANK YOU**

Answer (score 0):

When using case statement, don't forget to use break.In the following situation, if you forget to use it, the data will not be copied to the user layer

```c
switch (stack->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.IoControlCode) {
    case IOCTL_SEND: {
      SENDMessage(p_buffer);
      break;
    }
    case IOCTL_RECV: {
      RECVMessage(p_buffer) 
      break; // dont forget it
    }
    default: {
      nStatus = STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER;
    }
```