# Unable to receive anything in the Rust's output buffer from C++ Kernel Driver

Tags: c++, winapi, rust, driver

As the title says, I'm not able to receive anything from the C++ Kernel Driver, although I know for a fact that the output buffer is being properly set in C++.

C++ code:

```
        PVOID outputBuffer = Irp->UserBuffer;
        LONG outputBufferLength = irpStack->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.OutputBufferLength

        LONG tempVmFullAccessCount = g_VmFullAccessCount;
        KdPrint(("Long size: %d\n", sizeof(LONG)));
        LONG constValue = 123;
        RtlCopyMemory(outputBuffer, &constValue, sizeof(LONG));
        information = sizeof(LONG);
        KdPrint(("Output buffer value: %d\n", *((PLONG)outputBuffer)));
```

Rust code:

```
    let mut bytes_returned: DWORD = 0;
    
    let mut buffer: [u8; 4] = [0; 4];
    let output_buffer = buffer.as_mut_ptr() as PVOID;

    let result: BOOL = unsafe {
        DeviceIoControl(
            h_device,
            IOCTL_NOTIFY_USERMODE_APP,
            null_mut(),
            0,
            output_buffer,
            size_of::<i32>() as u32,
            &mut bytes_returned as *mut DWORD,
            null_mut(),
        )
    };

    if result != FALSE {
        // Handle the result
        println!("Bytes returned: {}", bytes_returned);
        println!("VM Full Access Counter: {}", vm_full_access_counter);
        println!("Size of i32: {}", size_of::<i32>());

        vm_full_access_counter = i32::from_ne_bytes(buffer);
        println!("VM Full Access Counter: {}", vm_full_access_counter);
    } else {
        eprintln!("DeviceIoControl failed. Error: {}", unsafe { winapi::um::errhandlingapi::GetLastError() });
    }
```

output_buffer is always [0,0,0,0]. I tried so many things, such as passing the variable directly instead of passing an u8 buffer

```
    let mut vm_full_access_counter: i32 = 100;
    let mut bytes_returned: DWORD = 0;
    
    let result: BOOL = unsafe {
        DeviceIoControl(
            h_device,
            IOCTL_NOTIFY_USERMODE_APP,
            null_mut(),
            0,
            &mut vm_full_access_counter as *mut i32 as PVOID,
            size_of::<i32>() as u32,
            &mut bytes_returned as *mut DWORD,
            null_mut(),
        )
    };

    if result != FALSE {
        // Handle the result
        println!("Bytes returned: {}", bytes_returned);
        println!("VM Full Access Counter: {}", vm_full_access_counter);
        println!("Size of i32: {}", size_of::<i32>());

        let raw_ptr = &mut vm_full_access_counter as *mut i32;
        let value = unsafe { *raw_ptr };
        println!("VM Full Access Counter: {}", value);
    } else {
        eprintln!("DeviceIoControl failed. Error: {}", unsafe { winapi::um::errhandlingapi::GetLastError() });
    }
```

The result of the variable/buffer is always 0.

Couple of important things:

1. Checked the LONG and i32 for size, they are 4 bytes
2. The outputBuffer variable from C++ is for sure being written, the kernel prints 123
3. Something is being written to vm_full_access_counter variable in Rust, as it is not 100 upon logging it again after DeviceIoControll call. It is 0.
4. Bytes returned is 4
5. I have trie adding timer with Arc & Mutex and loggining the buffer variable to make sure that it's not receiveing any delayed updates, although it makes no sense due to #3.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41429684/8182118 seems to have an answer to the same issue, you might want to give it a shot?

Comment: This may be really helpful. Thanks for digging it up, I noticed that there's a completely different function being used lol. If I find anything I'll post the answer as always, in case you are interested :D Thanks!

Comment: Does a C program calling DeviceIoControl get the expected result?

Comment: Damn, that's another nice idea. That's why I'm unemployed . . . I'm trying it ATM with the ChatBots.

Comment: Doesn't work in C, too! It's something related to the driver, I think that RtlCopyMemory is not what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it....

```
PVOID outputBuffer = Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
```

The buffer I was writting to was not of the correct type.